# Find exact match on multiple occurrences of a word

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a way to make a regex match only the super exact once as with `beauty-stuff` wording in this example?

[image]

I have a regex posted below:

```
labels = beauty|beauty-stuff|beauty-salon|beauty-bar
```

It matches the first word as the match result.

Comment: What do you mean by 'match the super exact one' ? can you give an example of what texts are matching?

Comment: If string is `labels/beauty-stuff` it keeps getting `beauty` as the match result... I want regex to get `beauty-stuff` as the match result instead of `beauty` @YouneL

Comment: the regex expression from the example is `/beauty|beauty-stuff|beauty-salon|beauty-bar/` @YouneL

Comment: How about `/\bbeauty-(stuff|salon|bar)\b/`?

Comment: In defining `labels` please include quotes around the string so that it is a valid Ruby expression. Also, it's best to avoid showing pictures of code. Links have a way of breaking over time and readers cannot cut and paste your code (though here the regex is quite short).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order stuff by descending length. `/beauty|beauty-stuff/` will find `beauty` in both `"labels/beauty"` and `"labels/beauty-stuff"`; `/beauty-stuff|beauty/` (or its more optimised version, `/beauty(?:-stuff|)/`) will find `beauty-stuff` in `"labels/beauty-stuff"`, `beauty` in `"labels/beauty"`. This works because regex will always return the first matching alternation (at the earliest matching position).